# Preg_match: как с ним работать?

Tags: php

Подскажите где можно узнать про этот тег поподробнее

```
preg_match("|<[^>]+>(.*)</[^>]+>|U",$mytext,$out, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

или точнее, какую и как прописывать информацию, находящуюся в двойных кавычках, как прочитал про него это шаблон, но этот набор символов по любому имеет какую-то закономерность, где это можно узнать?

Answer (score 1):

Функция [preg`_`match`_`all()](http://php.su/functions/?preg-match-all) выполняет проверку соответствия и возвращает в соответствии с флагом `PREG_PATTERN_ORDER` - массив вхождений.
В данном случае ищет в `$mytest` соответствие [регулярному выражению:](http://citforum.ru/internet/perl_tut/re.shtml)

```
|<[^>]+>(.*)]+>|U
```

И записывает в массив `$out`. Здесь:

```
| - Знак альтернативы (или)
^ - привязка к началу строки
[] - класс символов
. - метасимвол, означает один произвольный символ
* - модификатор, пишется после метасимвола, означает 0 или большее кол-во раз
U - Инвертирсия "жадности" для каждого квантификатора
```

Можно почитать тут:
1. [Введение в регулярные выражения. Синтаксис.](http://www.providerz.ru/articles/php/regexp-intro.html)
2. [Регулярные выражения (шаблоны).](http://citforum.ru/internet/perl_tut/re.shtml)
3. [Проверка регулярных выражений. Онлайн тестер](http://www.regexpr.ru/)
Ну и радует, что шаблоны уже все написаны, так что придумывать не приходится.

Answer (score 0):

читайте про [Регулярные выражения](http://phpclub.ru/detail/article/regexp_1)

Comment: >_< удалил свой ответ с этой же ссылкой